# Why can I not query this Azure AD app registration created by Terraform via AZCLI?

Tags: azure

I made an Azure AD App registration via Terraform.
I can see it via the Azure console and I can see it has a client and object ID. I'm trying to get the client ID via the AZCLI to automate something unrelated. However, I am completely unable to query this application via the AZCLI.

I created the following via Terraform:

```
resource "azuread_application" "test" {
  display_name = "something-something-microsoft"
}
```

Then I try to execute the following commands:

```
$ az ad sp list --display-name something-something-microsoft
[]
$ az ad sp show --id d5f75adb-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-1473334f1386
Resource 'd5f75adb-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-1473334f1386' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.
```

I am in the same subscription and tenant in both the CLI and the UI.

When I do the exact same thing via the UI, it magically does work.
The applications made from the UI and via Terraform differ, however when I edit the one created by Terraform manually to contain all the same options, making it EXACTLY the same, I'm STILL not able to query it via AZCLI.

When I try to filter the entire list of application I am also unable to find the app registration
`az ad sp list --all | jq '.[].displayName' | grep something`

I honestly don't understand why and I've been trying to figure this out for the better part of this entire day. I'm at my wits end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to fetch Azure AD app registration created by Terraform via AZCLI and I was able to do it successfully.

I tried provisioning an application using terraform as mentioned.

**main.tf**

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
  subscription_id = " "
  client_id       = " "
  tenant_id       = " "
  client_secret   = " "
}

resource "azuread_application" "test" {
  display_name = "something-something-microsoft"
}
```

**Output:**

step `terraform_apply`

[image]

**Resource application in portal:**

[image]
Initially tired with the command as mentioned in the query and I ended up facing the same error.

The main cause for the error is the commands used in CLI.

```
$ az ad sp list --display-name <>
$ az ad sp show --id <>
$ az ad sp list --all | jq '.[].displayName' | grep <>
```

But as per the query we are trying to fetch the data of the application which we create using terraform not the service principal as we cannot create one using terraform.

So, for the cases where we created an application using terraform and try to fetch the details using CLI we need to run the commands mentioned in the Document.

The `commandlets` supposed to be as mentioned.

```
az ad app show --id <>
```

&

```
az ad app list --display-name <>
```

**Output in CLI:**

[image]

&

[image]

Comment: I swear I checked `az ad --help` for similar commands... Oh well, thanks a bunch!